# How can I install flask for python38-32 using command prompt

Tags: python

I need to install flask for `Python38-32` in Windows10. I tried doing that from

Python cmd - `pip install flask`

```
Invalid syntax
```

PowerShell and Cmd prompt

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install flask'
```

I have added `Environment Variable` in `Path`, below path

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
```

I tried moving to path `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` in `cmd` and executed

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Getting error

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python>python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

After disabling App in Execution Aliases

```
C:\Users\Username>python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I do `easy_install`

```
C:\Users\Username>easy_install
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\easy_install.exe" '
```

How can I install flask?

Comment: Have you installed python from microsoft store?

Comment: @xcodz-dot - No, I have installed it from outside.

Comment: tried this? `disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases` as it says in the last error line

Comment: @xcodz-dot - I didn't try. Don't know what is that.

Comment: go to settings, search `Manage App Execution Aliases` and disable the shortcut for installing python

Comment: the problem has no connection to flask

Comment: @xcodz-dot - please check my updated question.

Comment: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\` add this to path also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added Environment variable in `path`, below location

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Tools\scripts
```

Opened command prompt, moved to `C:/` drive and executed below commands

```
python get-pip.py
```

and

```
pip install flask
```

It's Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `flask whl` from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/#files)

Then use `pip install Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`